# Replicating all couchbase buckets from one cluster to another using XDCR

Tags: couchbase

Two questions:

1) Is there any way to setup a bidirectional replication of **all** couchbase buckets between two clusters (without manually creating a replication between each of the buckets)

2) I'm creating buckets dynamically using the Java SDK, I would like to create and replicate a bucket created on a cluster automatically onto the other, is there anyway to do this using the Java SDK?

Answer (score 1):

There is not presently a trivial way to establish bi-directional replication for all buckets on one cluster to corresponding buckets on another cluster. Nor is there a programatic Java API for managing XDCR replications.

There is however a [REST API](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/rest-api/rest-xdcr-intro.html) for managing XDCR replications that could be used to programatically create replications. With a little bit of work using other aspects of the REST API this could be made to provide a solution for your first question also.

The [couchbase-cli](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/cli/cbcli-intro.html) tool is a command-line friendly wrapper around a significant portion of the REST API and it should be possible to create shell scripts using it to accomplish what you require if you are adverse to interacting with the REST API directly.